# Trying to make a wrapper to handle some repetitive code in React; how to use arguments?

Tags: reactjs

I have some repetitive code showing up in my React project. This repetitive JSX contains JSX that is different from page to page. I want to put the repetitive JSX in its own file and wrap it around the code that changes. This would be easy if I didn't need to change some class names and prop values used in the wrapping JSX.

Examples of my repetitive code are as follows:

Home.js

```js
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <article id="home" className="main-container d-flex">
                <Sidebar shrink={this.props.breakpoints[1]} />
                <section id="home_feed" className="center-page">
                    <MobileTopBar path={window.location.pathname} />
                    <div className="page-content mobile_bar-spacer">
                        // the content between this div changes from page to page...
                     // but the jsx I included is the same across all pages!
                    </div>
                    <MobileBottomBar />
                </section>
                <Rightbar
                    pageIsWiderThan1005px={this.props.breakpoints[2]}
                    onSearchPage={false}
                />
        </article>
    );
}
}
```

And so on for like 5 more pages.

What I want is to put the repetitive lines into a wrapper or HOC. Here is my newb attempt:

```js
import React from "react";

export function PageWrapper(WrappedComponent, props) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            // i want to use these variables
            console.log(pageName, sectionName, onSearchPage, breakpoints);
            return (
                <article id={pageName} className="main-container d-flex">
                    <Sidebar shrink={breakpoints[1]} />
                    <section id={sectionName} className="center-page">
                        <MobileTopBar path={window.location.pathname} />
                        <WrappedComponent/>
                        <MobileBottomBar />
                    </section>
                    <Rightbar
                        pageIsWiderThan1005px={breakpoints[2]}
                        onSearchPage={onSearchPage}
                    />
                </article>
            );
        }
    };
}

export default PageWrapper;
```

The idea is that I would pass the parts that vary from page to page in as the `WrappedComponent` and return the result of the wrapper. But I couldn't figure out how to pass the arguments.

I hoped I could pass in an argument like this:

```js
export default PageWrapper(Home, {pageName="home", sectionName="home_feed", onSearchPage=false});

// or maybe...

export default WithPageWrapper({pageName="home", sectionName="home_feed", onSearchPage=false})(Home);
```

...and export the logic for the breakpoints into the HOC itself (they are booleans based on window.innerWidth). I failed to find an example to mimic on the internet, however.

After reading about HOCs for like an hour without finding what I want, I came across something called a wrapper, which seemed a lot like a HOC but apparently is different.

It seems promising but I don't understand how to get the arguments into the wrapper. I think it'll show up something like this:

```js
<PageWrapper pageName="home" sectionName="home_feed">
    <Home/>
</PageWrapper>
```

... where `<Home/>` is the content that changes, in its own file...

but the rest is a mystery.

edit to include my error msg:

so, I edited my code a bit after reading @sallf say "your code should be doing what you want". This is what I ended up with:

```js
import SearchBase from "./SearchBase";
import Wrapper from "../helper/PageWrapper";

import "./Search.scss";

class Search extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.breakpoints);
        return (
            <Wrapper
                pageName="home"
                sectionName="home_feed"
                onSearchPage={true}
                breakpoints={this.props.breakpoints}
            >
                <SearchBase />
            </Wrapper>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Wrapper:

```js
export function PageWrapper(WrappedComponent, props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <article id={props.pageName} className="main-container d-flex">
            <Sidebar shrink={props.breakpoints[1]} />
            <section id={props.sectionName} className="center-page">
                <MobileTopBar path={window.location.pathname} />
                <WrappedComponent />
                <MobileBottomBar />
            </section>
            <Rightbar
                pageIsWiderThan1005px={props.breakpoints[2]}
                onSearchPage={props.onSearchPage}
            />
        </article>
    );
}

export default PageWrapper;
```

but logging props in the Wrapper just gives me an empty object?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
PageWrapper
C:/Users/me/Documents/postmassiv/frontend/src/pages/helper/PageWrapper.js:12
   9 | console.log(props);
  10 | return (
  11 |     <article id={props.pageName} className="main-container d-flex">
> 12 |         <Sidebar shrink={props.breakpoints[1]} />
     | ^  13 |         <section id={props.sectionName} className="center-page">
  14 |             <MobileTopBar path={window.location.pathname} />
  15 |             <WrappedComponent />
```

Comment: It sounds like you should use a wrapper component - though I'm not sure I fully followed. Your last code block with `<PageWrapper>` seems like it should be doing what you want. Is it not? I would just make that your `Home.js` file, instead of having a third file that contains both the wrapper and component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but maybe this will help.

```js
class Wrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <article id={this.props.pageName}>
        { this.props.children }
      </article>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper pageName="Home">
        // all the content that specific to home goes here
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper pageName="Search">
        // all the content that specific to search goes here
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like `Search` and `SearchBase` should probably just be one component. Also the "cannot read property of undefined" error means that prop `breakpoints` is undefined. From what you've shown in your last code block, you're not passing `breakpoints` as a prop to `PageWrapper`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. It was exactly what I needed to know.For anyone else who reads this thread, my mistake while doing research was that I didn't go in and find out what {this.props.children} does in the Wrapper component. I saw it written before but didn't understand that it transfers the contents of the ```Wrapper``` into the location of {this.props.children}. That was totally my fault. In summary: Try out the code you find while doing research!

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the PageWrapper a component that takes the changing content from the props. Therefore you could use the 'children' prop and use it as follows:

In your wrapper you add this.props.children.

```
import React from "react";

return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <article id={this.props.pageName} className="main-container d-flex">
                <Sidebar shrink={breakpoints[1]} />
                <section id={this.props.sectionName} className="center-page">
                    <MobileTopBar path={window.location.pathname} />
                    <div>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                    <MobileBottomBar />
                </section>
                <Rightbar
                    pageIsWiderThan1005px={breakpoints[2]}
                    onSearchPage={onSearchPage}
                />
            </article>
        );
    }
};

export default PageWrapper;
```

Now you can use PageWrapper in any component (Like home for example) like this:

```
import PageWrapper from './PageWrapper';

<PageWrapper pageName="Home" sectionName="Home">
    // Your content
</PageWrapper>
```